# Requesting Styled Google Maps XYZ tiles with QGIS seems to ignore colors

Tags: qgis-3, google-maps, tiles

At the time of posting this question unauthenticated requests for Google Maps tiles work.

E.g. the following [URL](https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x=3850&y=6771&z=14&apistyle=s.e%3Al.i%7Cp.v%3Aoff&s=Galileo&style=api%7Csmartmaps) scheme would correctly load the tile shown below

```
https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&
apistyle=s.e%3Al.i%7Cp.v%3Aoff&s=Galileo&style=api%7Csmartmaps
```

[image: Google Maps tile with icons removed]

Note that this is a styled tile as `s.e:l.i|p.v:off` style directive turns icon visibility off. Without this directive a highway number sign would be visible.

This works as an XYZ tile layer in QGIS 3.

However setting custom colors would not work. For example to make the roads grey I would add an additional style directive `s.t:3|s.e:g|p.c:#ffe0e0e0`.

The modified [URL](https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D&apistyle=s.e%3Al.i%7Cp.v%3Aoff%2Cs.t%3A3%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe0e0e0&s=Galileo&style=api%7Csmartmaps) scheme:

```
https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&apistyle=s.e%3Al.i%7Cp.v%3Aoff
%2Cs.t%3A3%7Cs.e%3Ag%7Cp.c%3A%23ffe0e0e0&s=Galileo&style=api%7Csmartmaps
```

Produces the expected modified result.

[image: Google Maps tile with changed road color]

However the corresponding XYZ Tile layer in QGIS seems to ignore this directive and still shows the roads white.

[image: QGIS window image with roads color unchanged]

Is there a way to customize Google Maps tile colors in QGIS?